# Touching food after washing mayim acharonim

Tags: mayim-acharonim

After one washes *mayim acharonim*, is it permissible to touch food? This can happen frequently because the table may be dirty and one may want to brush it off before putting down a *bentcher*.

According to the Mishna Berurah 181:1, there are two reasons for the obligation to wash mayim acharonim.

1. Hands are dirty after a meal and one is not allowed to make a blessing with dirty hands.
2. Every meal contains salt and there is a concern that there may be salt from Sodom mixed in which may blind a person who touches it and then touches their eyes.

Do we say that both of these reasons apply after touching food, and therefore one would be required to wash again after touching food, or do we say that the Rabbis instituted *mayim acharonim* only after eating, and not for someone who simply touches food?